# Update Unsecure, Secure, and Cookie URLs in phpMyAdmin from Production to Staging

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, cookie, base-url

I'm looking for a way to quickly update all unsecure, secure, and cookie domain URLs through phpMyAdmin.

My situation is to change unsecure & secure URLs (I use always-on HTTPS)

> from
>
> https://**www**.website.com
>
> to
>
> https://**staging**.website.com

and change Cookie domains

> from
>
> **www**.website.com
>
> to
>
> **staging**.website.com

Is there a quick way I can reference the `core_config_data` table for a search and replace of **www** with **staging** in rows `web/unsecure/base_url`, `web/secure/base_url`, and `web/cookie/cookie_domain` ?

This would help to fool-proof any updates when staging is rebuilt from production and make it quicker than finding each row and updating manually.

I am aware of changes to be made in local.xml and flushing of cache - that's a simple task I can complete after running this Search & Replace command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
use [database-name];

update core_config_data
set value = replace(value, 'www', 'staging')
where path in ('web/unsecure/base_url', 'web/secure/base_url', 'web/cookie/cookie_domain');
```

And if you want to do a 'dry-run' just to check which old values will be replaced by which new values:

```
select value 'Old Value', replace(value, 'www', 'staging') 'New Value'
from core_config_data
where path in ('web/unsecure/base_url', 'web/secure/base_url', 'web/cookie/cookie_domain');
```

Comment: Awesome! The "dry run" worked perfectly. Thank you!